# Logging in a social media (facebook, twitter etc) in a hybrid mobile application through javascript

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-authentication, hybrid-mobile-app

My **hybrid mobile application** (for android and iOS possibly windows as well) requires users to **authenticate** in Facebook.

How should I setup the Facebook application (**mobile** application or **web** application) since I am using **Javascript SDK**

If I need to setup the application as a web app, How should I configure the app domain and site URLs in Facebook application as the files are going to reside in the local app folders of the hybrid mobile application.

If I need to setup the application as a mobile app, How can I use the **Javascript SDK**?

Comment: Maybe it can help https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery?locale=fr_FR ??

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth Login system verfication helps to increase the registration , since your application is hybrid and its a mobile based you need to create a php based web login auth to authenticate the login , there are many an enumeros website that help in aiding to achive the determined goal of this, the first thing is to create a facebook application , secondly you need to configure App Id and App Secret ( this will require you to input details about your domains and other information related to the app infos ) , your solution can be found here www.oauthlogin.com also check this out simply download and implement video instruction out there http://www.9lessons.info/2011/09/update-login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register your app with facebook to get developers API Apps Id and App Secret.
you have to follow a screenshot of Friends Invite from Facebook in the links below.
http://www.webtuts.info/webdevelopment/facebook-api-invite-friends-website/172/
 The set up are all the same and that is what am using in my phonegap app to set facebook login authentication. Once you have created an account with facebook, you can follow a tutorial in the link below to build your facebook login for IOS,Windows and Android etc
http://asif18.com/5/facebook/facebook-login-using-php-sdk-and-javascript-sdk/

You can write back if you find it difficult to integrate. Rate this  response if you findin it helpful.  Thanks